# Create a scoreboard for football

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to flutter and i am looking for days to find a way to design with flutter
a table score of clubs in a soccer league , and i also was searching for other designs or anything that can help me to do it easy but i almost did not find anything,
i am searching for something like this ( just design)

[image: tablescore]

[image: upcoming match]

I really have no idea even even how to do anything similar or close to it, any help will be so appreciated.

Update : here what i did but the table do not scroll to the last index

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LeagueBoard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text("TableBoard"),
   ),
   body: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
       children: [
         TopRow(),
         ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
           physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
           itemCount: 20,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return TableRow(index: index);
           },
         ),
       ],
     ),
   ),
    );
  }
}

class TopRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopRow({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          child: Text('#'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
        Container(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Team')),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          child: Text('#'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 30,
          child: Text('MP'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 20,
          child: Text('W'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 100,
          child: Text('D'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 100,
          child: Text('L'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 100,
          child: Text('GD'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 50,
          child: Text('Pts'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20)
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TableRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  const TableRow({
    this.index,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 30,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.5),
        color: Colors.grey[300],
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            color: index < 4
                ? Colors.blue
                : index == 4
                ? Colors.red[700]
                : index > 16
                ? Colors.red
                : Colors.grey[700],
            child: Text(
              (index + 1).toString(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10),
          Container(
              width:50,
              child: Text('Team name#${index + 1}')),
          //Spacer(),
          Container(
            width: 40,
            child: Text('MP#${index + 1}'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 40,
            child: Text('W#${index + 1}'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 40,
            child: Text('D#${index + 1}'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 40,
            child: Text('L#${index + 1}'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 80,
            child: Text('GD#${index + 1}'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 50,
            child: Text('Pts#${index + 1}'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 5,
            height: 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              color: Colors.grey[600],
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 2, 5),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at DataTables: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html

Comment: is that the only way to do it? what about the second image?

Comment: Oh no, there are always plenty of ways to do it. What about the second image? Try to post some code (Minimal, Complete, Reproducible) and specific questions to get more targeted answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can start of with something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Scoreboard'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              TopRow(),
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 30,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return TableRow(index: index);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopRow({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 11);

    return Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          child: Text('#'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
        Container(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Team')),
        Spacer(),
        Container(
          width: 28,
          child: Text('MP', style: textStyle),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 28,
          child: Text('W', style: textStyle),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 28,
          child: Text('D', style: textStyle),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 28,
          child: Text('L', style: textStyle),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 28,
          child: Text('G', style: textStyle),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 28,
          child: Text('Pts', style: textStyle),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 5,
          height: 20,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            color: Colors.grey[600],
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 2, 5),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TableRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  const TableRow({
    this.index,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 11);
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 30,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.5),
        color: index == 3 || index == 4 ? Colors.yellow[200] : Colors.grey[300],
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            color: index < 4
                ? Colors.blue
                : index == 4
                    ? Colors.red[700]
                    : index > 16
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.grey[700],
            child: Text(
              (index + 1).toString(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20),
          Text('Team name#${index + 1}', style: textStyle),
          Spacer(),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('MP${index + 1}', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('W${index + 1}', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('D${index + 1}', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('L${index + 1}', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('G${index + 1}', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('Pts${index + 1}', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 5,
            height: 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              color: Colors.grey[600],
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 2, 5),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: the table is not scrolling when i launch it

Comment: This is strange because this is what `SingleChildScrollView` there for. If it does not fit the screen it is scrollable

Comment: i will update my answer and show you what i did

Comment: i also tried to added the missing columns in the table but it appears that it is not reponsive and there is a problem in display

Comment: I got where it comes - add `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` to `ListView` properties. I updated the code.

Comment: if we will solve the problem of the missing fields , then it is done , i am very grateful for all your help

Comment: thank you so much man , you saved my week, i wish that i will be one day talented like you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) widget to achieve that. The link has an informative video.

Here's a quick and dirty complete example of how you can achieve what you want. You can try it out on [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/7f0734cf47c450184cdf37c5a1a94bf2?null_safety=false):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Table Example'),
      ),
      body: MyTable(),
    );
  }
}

class MyTable extends StatelessWidget {
  TableRow createRow(TeamData data, int rank) {
    return TableRow(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: rank.isOdd ? Colors.blue[50] : Colors.white,
        ),
        children: [
          Text('$rank'),
          Row(children: [
            FlutterLogo(
              size: 24.0,
            ),
            Text('${data.name}')
          ]),
          Text('${data.mp}'),
          Text('${data.w}'),
          Text('${data.d}'),
          Text('${data.pts}'),
        ]);
  }

  List<TableRow> rows() {
    // sort the data
    data.sort((team1, team2) => team2.pts.compareTo(team1.pts));
    return List.generate(data.length, (index) => createRow(data[index], index));
  }

  TableRow header() {
    return TableRow(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue[50],
      ),
      children: [
        Text('rank'),
        Text('team'),
        Text('mp'),
        Text('w'),
        Text('d'),
        Text('pts'),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Table(
          defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
          children: [
           header(),
          ...rows(),
        ]));
  }
}

final data = [
  TeamData(name: 'MC United', mp: 12, w: 13, d: 14, pts: 56),
  TeamData(name: 'Chelsea', mp: 12, w: 13, d: 14, pts: 31),
  TeamData(name: 'PSG', mp: 12, w: 13, d: 14, pts: 10),
  TeamData(name: 'Barcelona', mp: 12, w: 13, d: 14, pts: 40),
  TeamData(name: 'Real Madrid', mp: 12, w: 13, d: 14, pts: 13),
  TeamData(name: 'Bayren Munich', mp: 12, w: 13, d: 14, pts: 43),
];

class TeamData {
  final String name;
  final int mp;
  final int w;
  final int d;
  final int pts;

  TeamData({
    this.name,
    this.mp,
    this.w,
    this.d,
    this.pts,
  });
}
```

You can do a lot with styling both the table and text to make it look however you like. Ultimately, everything inside the table is a just a bunch of Widgets wrapped in `TableRow`s. So you can put whatever widget you like inside the table to achieve what you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i feel the styling is so far of what i wanted , can you tell me which properties of styling i should change exeactly to find something close to what i am searching for ?

Comment: and also i have an error when i launch your code : A RenderFlex overflowed by 23 pixels on the right. here in this line   Row(children: [
            FlutterLogo(
              size: 24.0,
            ),
            Text('${data.name}')
          ]),

Comment: @FaresBenSlama there's nothing built-in, you've to do the styling yourself. Flutter is just a UI framework that allows you to create UI but doesn't give you template for everything you need.

Comment: and what about the error that i got , i wrote it in the second comment